# Why can't I pipe a BehaviourSubject?

Tags: rxjs

I'm not sure why `subscribe` works with `BehaviourSubject` but not `pipe`.

For example, the code below prints out?

```
subscribe: 123
subscribe: 456
```

Why doesn't it also print

```
pipe: 123
pipe: 456
```

Code:

```
import {tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

const subject = new BehaviorSubject(123);
subject.subscribe(p => console.log("subscribe: " + p));
subject.pipe(
  tap(p => {console.log("pipe:" + p);})
)
subject.next(456);
```

Comment: Because you never subscribe to the observable returned by subject.pipe(...)

Comment: Thanks.. adding a subscribe() call worked as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subject.pipe(
  tap(p => {console.log("pipe:" + p);})
)
```

You are only tapping into the observable here. You will need to subscribe separately in this subject for the tapping to work. The following code will give you the desired console log:

```
subject.pipe(
  tap(p => {console.log("pipe:" + p);})
).subscribe();
```

If you must subscribe only once, then you could try the following code:

```
const abc$ = new BehaviorSubject(123).asObservable().pipe(
  tap((val) => console.log('pipe: ', val))
);
abc$.subscribe((val) => console.log('subscribe: ', val));
```